# Unable to add Video to react-native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Facing problem while adding video to my App I have installed `react-native-video` and have linked via `react-native link` in project folder

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Video} from 'react-native-video';
import LightVideo from "./big_buck_bunny.mp4"

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
<View >
  <Text > React Native Video </Text>
  <Video
    source={LightVideo}
    resizeMode="cover"
    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}

      />
 </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Error message image -->**
[Screen shot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbaIn.jpg)

Comment: Above **Error Message description** link is screen shot of error message

Answer (score 1):

Instead of default import, you are doing named import.

Use

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
```

instead of

```
import {Video} from 'react-native-video';
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. Matches the react-native-video package's own examples.

Comment: your answer really helps a lot. It solves my problem.